# iOS app rejected - private symbol mach_init_routine

Tags: ios, private, symbols, appstore-approval

recently the update to one of our apps was rejected because we possibly use private apis. the funny thing is: the app only consists of a simple uiwebview that loads a sencha touch javascript application (local) and the update only changed some javascript, no native code at all.

upon request apple disclosed that this app possibly uses the following private symbols:

- __keymgr_dwarf2_register_sections
- _cthread_init_routine
- mach_init_routine

as the only 'handwritten' code of this application is ~5 lines long (get html code and baseurl + pass it to the uiwebview) we have no idea where this is coming from.

any help / hints would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE: Not at all apples fault - it was the sencha jsbuilder mac app that was accidentially added to the projects resources**

Comment: I'd say someone is being overzealous at Apple. Resubmit your app telling them ur not using any private APIs and I bet you it will get approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like low-level process-management stuff to me. `__keymgr_dwarf2_register_sections` might be something to do with debugging, although a bit of googling suggests it may be involved in exception handling.

I would guess that your old and new versions differ in some detail of the compilation: check your build configuration and compiler flags, and compiler and glibc versions carefully, with particular reference to debugging and exception handling.

You could try compiling the source to the old version with your current setup, and then using `strings | grep` to see if it contains any of the offending symbols. If it does, that's a smoking gun pointing to a change in the build process.

Comment: thank you for the hint about build settings, will try that and hopefully this solves the problem

Comment: oh damn, i feel really stupid - didn't clean the senacha touch distribution, so their jsbuilder mac application was added to my projects resources ;-) - still, apple did not care for that in v1.0 submitted two weeks ago ... anyway accepted because grep pointed it out :) - thank you